# Connection strings limit in web.config .net

Tags: .net, web-config

I tried googling this question about, how many connection strings does .NET allow to have in my web.config (meaning what is the maximum number of connection string allowed in web.config)?  Is there an limit?

Comment: There is no limit on number of connection strings in web.config. But I think it's not practical to have more than 3 connection strings in a web.config file, because why do you need to connect to many databases? What are the reasons for that?
Because each connection string is a maintenance point in a .NET app development perspective.

Comment: Please elaborate your use-case. This seems like a strange situation unless you're generating the web.config using a script.